# Removing text after character c

Tags: c, text, input, output, stdio

I have some text that looks like this, from an input file:

```
func:
    sll  $t3, $t4, 5       # t1 = (i * 4)
    add  $t3, $a1, $t4     # t2 contains address of array[i]
    sw   $t1, 4($t2)       # array[i] = i
    addi $t2, $t5, 3       # i = i+1
```

I would like to "clean" it, and output it to another file looking like this:

```
func:
    sll  $t3, $t4, 5
    add  $t3, $a1, $t4
    sw   $t1, 4($t2)
    addi $t2, $t5, 3
```

Here is the code block I am using to do this:

```
    while(fgets(line, 100, input) != NULL)
   {
    int comment = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        if(line[x] == '#')
            comment = 1;

        if(comment == 1)
            line[x] = '\0'; //I know this is incorrect
    }
    fprintf(cleaned, "%s", line);
   }
```

How can I change that block of code to work as I want it to? I messed around and tried a few things with '\n' '\0' and " ", but none of it quite worked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way, but you don't need to set a flag. You can truncate the line right away and stop any further searching with `break;`

```
for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    if(line[x] == '#') {
        line[x] = '\n';
        line[x + 1] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this code in a debugger to see exactly what it is doing.  Put a break point in your outer `while` loop probably and step through a character at a time to precisely understand the behavior.  It will probably become apparent to you what to do next.

If on unix use `gdb`, compile your program with `-g` to include debugging information, and google something like "gdb cheatsheet" to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strchr` to find '#' in your line. If found, a pointer is returned and if not `NULL`.
You can the determine the difference between the start and the occurrence and create a new string.

```
/* strchr example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] = "This is a sample string";
    char * pch;
    printf ("Looking for the 's' character in \"%s\"...\n",str);
    pch=strchr(str,'s');
    while (pch!=NULL)
      {
        printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
        pch=strchr(pch+1,'s');
      }
    return 0;
}
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) for a reference.